# NHibernate MappingException

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have been interested in learning NHibernate, so i search a course, and i found one in Pluralsight, but when i go to follow the examples i get this exception and i don't know why i get this exception... and it's kind of annoying because where i search i can't find more info about the exception or an up-to-date guide of NHibernate. So my question is:
a) for the exception itself, why it occurs
b) if you can recommend me a site or a course or anything up to date to learn NHibernate.

Thanks in advance.

I leave the code here:

Customer.cs:

```
namespace NHibernateDemo
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public virtual int Id { get; set; }
        public virtual string FirstName { get; set; }
        public virtual string LastName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Customer.hbm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:hibernate-mapping-2.2"
                   assembly="NHibernateDemo"
                   namespace="NHibernateDemo">
  <class name="Customer">
    <id name="Id">
      <generator class="native"/>
    </id>
    <property name="FirstName"/>
    <property name="LastName"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;

namespace NHibernateDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cfg = new Configuration();
            cfg.DataBaseIntegration(x =>
            {
                x.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;Database=NHibernateDemo;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
                x.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                x.Dialect<MsSql2008Dialect>();
            });

            // Here is where i get the MappingException. It says that it can't compile the Customer.hbm.xml file.
            cfg.AddAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

            var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                using (var tx = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    var customers = session.CreateCriteria<Customer>()
                                           .List<Customer>();
                    foreach (var customer in customers)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", customer.FirstName, customer.LastName);
                    }
                    tx.Commit();
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to exit...");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Message of the exception:

```
"Could not compile the mapping document: NHibernateDemo.Customer.hbm.xml"
```

StackTrace:

```
    NHibernate.MappingException: Could not compile the mapping document: NHibernateDemo.Customer.hbm.xml ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Error en el documento XML (1, 2). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No se esperaba <hibernate-mapping xmlns='urn:hibernate-mapping-2.2'>.
   en Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderHbmMapping.Read109_hibernatemapping()
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.NamedXmlDocument..ctor(String name, XmlDocument document, XmlSerializer serializer)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.NamedXmlDocument..ctor(String name, XmlDocument document)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LoadMappingDocument(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LogAndThrow(Exception exception)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.LoadMappingDocument(XmlReader hbmReader, String name)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddInputStream(Stream xmlInputStream, String name)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddResource(String path, Assembly assembly)
   en NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.AddAssembly(Assembly assembly)
   en NHibernateDemo.Program.Main(String[] args) en d:\Sistema\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\NHibernateDemo\NHibernateDemo\Program.cs:línea 28
```

Comment: can you post the exception message please ?

Comment: Please read/post the complete exception message. This exception usually come with an inner exception giving more details, which may have itself its own inner exception and so forth. Usually, the faster and easier way to have complete exception message is to call `.ToString()` on the exception, or click "Copy exception details to clipboard" if you are in a debug session under Visual Studio.

Comment: thanks, i don't know the "ToString" trick... i will update the error log now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found (thanks to Fréderic) that the problem was a line in the hbm.xml file. This line was the one that have make the problem occur: `<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:hibernate-mapping-2.2"`.
 I forgot a 'n' in front of the 'hibernate' word and because of that it can't parse the file.

Thanks to Taki and Fréderic for the time.

Comment: I guess it was the second `hibernate` which was at fault, the one in `xmlns` attribute value, not the tag name. So correct version is `<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"`. I would not have spot that without the complete error message.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Frédéric, is the second "hibernate" in the xmlns attribute value. I see that error in the complete error message. Thanks again for the advice

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that it can't find the file to compile it, so :

try manually copying the file into your `bin` directory ( `Debug` or `Release` or .. )

make sure your `NHibernateDemo.Customer.hbm.xml` properties are `Build Action : Embedded resource` and `Copy to Output Directory : Copy Always`

if you still have the problem, try adding : `cfg.AddFile("NHibernateDemo.Customer.hbm.xml")` ( or the path to your `hbm.xml` file )

if you still have the problem, then try : 
`cfg.addFile(AssemblyLocation() + "NHibernateDemo.Customer.hbm.xml");` ( or the path to your `hbm.xml` file, where `AssemblyLocation()` is  :

```
private string AssemblyLocation()
{
    var codebase = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

    return Path.GetDirectoryName(codebase.LocalPath);
}
```

`cfg.AddAssembly` isn't necessary so you might consider removing it  if none of the above works :P